# Poetry install private package started suddenly failing in Docker

Tags: docker, pypi, python-poetry

## ABOUT

MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE: https://gitlab.com/hynek.blaha/debug-docker-poetry/-/tree/master

I have been building Docker images using Poetry with Python packages from internal PyPI registry. As our projects are in private GitLab repository and the internal packages are not top-secret, we are storing the poetry credentials directly in the poetry source URL in `pyproject.toml`.

On **2022-08-24**, all our Docker builds started failing while installing internal package:

```bash
• Installing til-bigquery (0.3.4)

  HTTPError

  401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/38869805/packages/pypi/files/7a4731d831d4b37262481002271e359f96017570e9480ef16c89489e0b41252f/til_bigquery-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=7a4731d831d4b37262481002271e359f96017570e9480ef16c89489e0b41252f

  at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py:1021 in raise_for_status
      1017│                 f"{self.status_code} Server Error: {reason} for url: {self.url}"
      1018│             )
      1019│ 
      1020│         if http_error_msg:
    → 1021│             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
      1022│ 
      1023│     def close(self):
      1024│         
      1025│         called the underlying ``raw`` object must not be accessed again.
```

## What I found weird:

- Docker build fails even when I retry deploy job, that successfully passed a few days ago.
- Considering the issue might have been caused by unpinned minor version of Docker base image `python:3.7-slim` or Poetry, I used older versions but got the same result.
- I compared the build logs of previously successful build `build_success.log` (**8/22/22, 3:00 PM**) and the same build retry `build_fail.log` (**8/24/22, 6:00 AM**) and found both use the same poetry wheel `poetry-1.1.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

## It still works as before on my machine, but fails in Docker.

- It stops working on localhost when I remove the credentials from the repository URL, so I am sure the credentials are not stored anywhere else (e.g. ~/.netrc).

**How to reproduce:**

1. Localhost - OK

```bash
git clone git@gitlab.com:hynek.blaha/debug-docker-poetry.git
poetry install
```

2. Docker - FAIL

```bash
git clone git@gitlab.com:hynek.blaha/debug-docker-poetry.git
docker build .
```

I am able to fix the issue by explicitly providing the credentials in Dockerfile:

```bash
RUN pip install poetry --no-cache-dir && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry config repositories.my_private_repo https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/21870843/packages/pypi/simple && \
    poetry config http-basic.my_private_repo __token__ glpat-mkEPJ4Rsy2peTCrH23pG
```

**But it doesn't explain, why rebuilding the same image started failing.
And why it still works as expected when running on my machine (outside of Docker).**

Does anyone have an idea, what might have changed? I was unable to tell what even when using `diff` on the `build_success.log` and `build_fail.log`

Comment: Literally same issue for us, with a private repo. stopped working yesterday. Not sure what changed either as it was working yesterday AM, randomly stopped 2 hours later.

Comment: I also have this issue, still cannot find a solution, using Azure DevOps, not GitLab but maybe it's the same issue. If you find any thing out please update us, thanks

Answer (score 10):

I was struggling with totally the same problem the last few days. Though I'm still not sure of the exact cause, somehow I managed to avoid the problem.

I also used a repository URL with credentials embedded in `pyproject.toml` until yesterday like this.

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = 'private'
url = 'https://your_username:your_password@gitlabce.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple'
secondary = true
```

Though it's basically the same as your solution, you can specify the local poetry configs for each project by creating `poetry.toml` at the project root. So instead of embedding credentials in the URL, you can specify them via `poetry.toml` as follows:

```ini
[http-basic]
[http-basic.private]
username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"
```

That way, you can reproduce the same behaviour with embedded credentials without the authentication error.

##### Why does it still work outside docker?

I guess it is due to the archive cache in your local environment. Since poetry stores downloaded archives in `~/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/` and reuse them when execute `poetry install`, you didn't need to access your private PyPI server in the first place. If you manually remove archives (I'm not sure, but `poetry cache clear` command didn't work for my case), you'll be able to reproduce the authentication error even in your local environment.

##### Why did the error suddenly start to occur?

Poetry uses the embedded credentials to query the list of package links to the private PyPI server.
It works fine until there, however, when installing actual packages, Poetry uses the acquired link from the PyPI server that has no credentials embedded. That's why it fails and the URL shown in the error message doesn't have any credentials embedded.

I'm still not sure why the credential embed had been working until a few days ago though. I guess there might have been behavior changes on the GitLab side.

Comment: I think a recent gitlab change might be the cause of this. It looks like the only reason it worked previously was that Gitlab did not have any authentication on the acquired link(!). See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/351438 and maybe https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/7655

Comment: I still had to add `poetry config repositories.my_private_repo <url>` OR the corresponding `poetry.toml` configuration for this to work (using the `pyproject.toml`'s `[[tool.poetry.source]]` alone didn't do the trick).